# how to pass object into web service and consuming that web service

Tags: c#, web-services

consider following code..

```
[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    private string studentName;
    private double gpa;

    public Student() 
    {

    }

    public string StudentName
    {
        get{return this.studentName;}
        set { this.studentName = value; }
    }

    public double GPA 
    {
        get { return this.gpa; }
        set { this.gpa = value; }
    }


}
```

private ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddStudent(Student student) 
    {
        studentList.Add(student);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public ArrayList GetStudent() 
    {
        return studentList;
    }
```

I want to consume that web service using simple C# client form application.
I can't get the student list using following code segment..

MyServiceRef.Student student = new Consuming_WS.MyServiceRef.Student();

```
    MyServiceRef.Service1SoapClient client = new Consuming_WS.MyServiceRef.Service1SoapClient();
```

any idea..??

Thank in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any exception / error? You are not calling GetStudent() method of web service. If we return C# ArrayList from web service, can we really consume the same ArrayList from clients of other platforms? say Java client?

Comment: yes,I know..but the thing is i can't assign something like this.. ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();
            studentList = client.GetStudent(); this code segment does not work! any idea..?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your web service is not stateless. Each time the web service is called, a new instance of your web service class is instanced and the method is called on this instance. When the instance is called, studentList is assigned a new empty list.

You need to alter you state management. E.g.

```
private static ArrayList studentList = new ArrayList();
```

would probably work better but it is still not reliable. 
Check the article at http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/managing-state-web-service.aspx for a sample that stores the state in Session (or Application).

Edit: added sample code to avoid usage of ArrayList.

To avoid problems with ArrayList and ArrayOfAnyType:

```
private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

[WebMethod]
public void AddStudent(Student student) 
{
    studentList.Add(student);
}

[WebMethod]
public Student[] GetStudent() 
{
    return studentList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: :: Nop..the problem is still here. It says.."Cannot implicitly convert type 'Consuming_WS.MyServiceRef.ArrayOfAnyType' to 'System.Collections.ArrayList' "...Any idea..??

Comment: See my added sample above to work around this problem. The problem is that you are using ArrayList in web service interface.